# RunViewModelLifecycle in mvvmcross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am getting the following inner exception, I wonder what might cause this issue.

> MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.RunViewModelLifecycle
>   (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel viewModel,
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues,
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00039] in
>   :0    at
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.Load (System.Type
>   viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues,
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00028] in
>   :0    at
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel
>   (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request,
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState,
>   MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModelLocator viewModelLocator)
>   [0x00015] in :0

```
try
{
 // the following line always throws an exception.
  ShowViewModel<StudentViewModel >(new { studentId = Id, classroomId = SelectedClassroom });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(String.Concat(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message));

  if (ex.InnerException != null)
  {
     Debug.WriteLine("Inner Exception");
     Debug.WriteLine(String.Concat(ex.InnerException.StackTrace, ex.InnerException.Message));
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled Exception - mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121150/unhandled-exception-mvvmcross)

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe, any idea for the issue?

Comment: What are the types of `Id` and `SelectedClassroom`?

Comment: both are `string`

Comment: can you please close one of your questions? you posted it twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121150/unhandled-exception-mvvmcross

Comment: I have closed it.

Comment: whats the signature of the StudentViewModel Class?